# Rule to test whether two lists contain same two elements fails due to uniqueness constraint

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to create a rule called `redundancy` that examines lists to see if two elements appear together in more than one list.

Here is my code:

```
columns([a,b,c]).
columns([b,c,d]).

in(X, [H|_]) :-
    X = H.

in(X, [_|T]) :-
    in(X, T).

redundancy(X, Y) :-
    columns(A),
    columns(B),
    A \= B,         
    X \= Y,
    in(X, A),
    in(X, B),
    in(Y, A),
    in(Y, B).
```

The problem is the constraint `X \= Y`. I want it in there to exclude instances where X and Y are identical elements, which would be true for all single elements that appear in more than one list. But it only returns false for the given `columns` even though it should return permutations of `b` and `c`.

```
?- redundancy(U, T).
false.
```

If I comment out the constraint I get the expected elements along with the unwanted ones mentioned above.

```
?- redundancy(X, Y).
X = Y, Y = b ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
X = c,
Y = b ;
X = Y, Y = c ;
X = Y, Y = b ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
X = c,
Y = b ;
X = Y, Y = c ;
false.
```

Is there a way to enforce this constraint? I'm also interested in ideas to restrict results to a given combination of elements rather than permutations.

Comment: It worked when I took your advice and switched the predicate to dif or \==. If you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move `X \= Y` to the last line of your predicate. also, see [prolog-dif](/questions/tagged/prolog-dif) and [instantiation-error](/questions/tagged/instantiation-error).

The thing to avoid is using non-pure predicates with not-yet-instantiated logical variables (unless this is exactly what you intended, and you know what you're doing).

Another thing to notice is that `X \= Y` is not a constraint (that's `dif`), but a *check*.